# Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to find a prime larger than $n$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, computer-science

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to find a prime larger than $n$?

If Cramér's conjecture is true, we can use AKS to test $n+1$, $n+2$, etc. until the next prime is found, and this method will find a prime in polynomial time (in $\log n$) because AKS runs in polynomial time and Cramér's conjecture guarantees $O((\log{n})^2)$ primes to test.

Without assuming Cramér's conjecture, and without requiring that the prime to be found is the next prime following $n$, only that it is larger than $n$, can such a prime be found in time $O((\log{n})^k)$ for some $k$?

This question is motivated by some thoughts I wrote about in the comments on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/226465/1284) by Gerry Myerson.

Comment: Related [Deterministic Methods to Find Primes](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/polymath.pdf).

Comment: I read through the paper; it considers exactly this problem as well as some related ones and it is said to be open.  I would like to accept this as an answer.

Comment: Is this asking whether to find the next prime larger than $n$, or drawing a prime larger than $n$ following a specific distribution? Because if not, Maurer's algorithm with a suitable lower bound should get the job done.

Comment: (technically, it is probabilistic, but takes finite time and always returns a prime along with a provable primality certificate)

Answer (score 1):

This is Rick Sladkey's comment as a CW answer. An algorithm is given in [this paper](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/polymath.pdf): "Deterministic Methods to Find Primes".